# Irrational numbers in $[0,1]$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

> Why irrational numbers in interval $[0,1]$ can't be written as countable union of closed sets of $\mathbb R$?

My idea is the following:
Let: $$S=\mathbb Q^c\cap[0,1]=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}[a_i,b_i]$$  We can suppose every $[a_i,b_i]$ is disjoint from others and $[a_i,b_i]\subset[0,1]$. Now define: $$X=\{a_i,b_i\,;i\in \mathbb N\}$$ Then $X$ is close in $S$. because it's complement in $S$ is union of open set. So, $X$ is complete. $X$ is perfect. Let $\epsilon \gt0$ be given. Then: $(a_i-\epsilon,a_i)$ contain one of $b_j$. Similarly, every $b_i$ is a limit point of $X$. But we know every complete and perfect metric space is uncountable. So $X$ is uncountable. contradict.

Comment: And what did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: That was easy. it is related about one of mine real analysis exercises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: can be the complementary (rationals of interval) countable intersection of open sets? Also: Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know this is an old question but I'm a bit stuck trying to solve this problem. So we know by Baire Category theorem that $[0,1]$ (complete) cannot be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets. We also know that the rationals $Q$ can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets. It seems like this imply that $[0,1]-Q$ must not be nowhere dense i.e. contain an interior point? It doesn't seem right that the irrationals would contain an on open interval though. Also how does this show that $[0,1]-Q$ cannot be written as countable union of closed sets?

Comment: @TOMILO87, the interior of $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ is obviously empty because $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. Your "It seems like this imply that..." es false. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Unions_and_intersections_of_any_number_of_sets

Comment: But if the rationals is a countable union of nowhere dense sets $Q=\cup E_k$ where $E_k$ is nowhere dense and if $[0,1]-Q$ was also nowhere dense then wouldn't that mean that $[0,1]=(\cup E_k)\cup ([0,1]-Q)$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, contradicting Bair? I understand that I'm wrong here but I cannot see why. Thank you for link, I aware of these relations. But even if we establish that $Q^C = (\cup E_k)^C = \cap E_n^C$ I cannot see how it follows that $\cap E_n^C$ is not open which would show that $[0,1]-Q$ is not closed. Maybe I figure it out eventually.

Comment: @TOMILO87, alternatively, "a subset of a topological space is called nowhere dense if its closure has empty interior." The closure of $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q = [0,1]$. $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ **isn't** nowhere dense. Try this: using $\Bbb Q = \cup_{r\in\Bbb Q}\{r\}$, what is $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$?